# Gerrit hook to fire once per push event

Tags: git, gerrit, githooks

I am in need of a Gerrit hook that is similar in function to gits `post-receive` hook.  Need to do a notification *once* on each push.

Have tried Gerrit's `ref-update` and `ref-updated` - both seem to fire once per commit in the push.

Can accept the fact that the answer may be staring me in the fact and I simply cannot see the forest for the trees.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a Gerrit hook which works the way you want. If a "push" contains more than one commit, the Gerrit hooks will be fired once per commit.